# If ACF meta_key has meta_value

Tags: post-meta

I have an ACF field (options) that contains a list of options:

```
Blue
Red
Green
```

I would like to echo the option selected, ie:

```
if(get_field('blue') == true) {
  echo "You have selected the color Blue";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing out this troubling question, alas! the answer did fall from the heavens and presenteth itself unto me:

```
$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'options');

 if(in_array('blue',$meta)) {
   echo "You've selected blue, punk!";
}
```